# SocketIOClient on Xamarin doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, socket.io

I'm trying to use SocketIOClient on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, and it works corrrectly but only on imulators. When I start apps on real devices socket doesn't work and app just doesn't show any errors in try-catch blocks. May by anyone has same problem and fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this library [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet). If yes, I also have your problem on iOS. My solution is get the SocketIoClientDotNet code and rebuild in my xamarin project.

Checkout my demo here: 
https://github.com/tudushare/XamarinSocketIODemo

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference