# Xamarin.iOS app sockets not working on real device

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, websocket, xamarin.ios

We're currently working on a native cross-platform Xamarin App with Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android and a shared PCL project.

In this app we want to use WebSockets, Socket.IO to be more specific. Therefore we added the [SocketIoClient library](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) to our project. It connects to our server via WSS (Secure WebSockets) on the default port (443).

It's all working fine on Android and the iOS simulator. But for some reason it stops working as soon as one runs the app on a real iOS device.

Unfortunately, the log contains no error messages. But by obeserving the server log we figured out that no single request is received on the server side.

Comment: It''s hard to figure out your problem without any information,  try the demo in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037456/socketioclient-on-xamarin-doesnt-work-on-real-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the library SocketIoClientDotNet in your PCL project you should use it also in your Xamarin project. I had this problem too and this solved my problem.